# Path '/forum/default.asp' is forbidden

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, cassini

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 web app and part of the structure still has some legacy ASP under the folder /forum/. I haven recently moved my dev environment to a new machine and am now getting:

Path '/forum/default.asp' is forbidden

when trying to open a page with a .asp extension under the Cassini environment. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cassini doesn't run old ASP, it only runs the .NET environment.